# Firebase Auth with Azure SAML SSO

Tags: firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0

I've already been able to get a SAML SSO up and running perfectly using [this article](https://medium.com/@tfalvo/single-sign-on-sso-for-your-firebase-app-with-saml-f67c71e0b4d6).

However, when I try to replicate the steps using Azure as the IDP, I get the following error:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: SAML Response <Issuer> mismatch. (auth/invalid-credential).
```

I don't know why more info isn't provided in the error, but it's left me without a lot of options for how to fix it.

I'm setting up Azure using a non-gallery Enterprise App, assigning a user to the app, and attempting to sign in on the Firebase app using the SAMLAuthProvider and signInWithPopup (as outlined in the article). Here's what the SSO configuration screens look like for both Azure and Google Cloud Identity

[Configuration Screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAq5O.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Azure AD is the IDP, and "Firebase" is the SP, so it looks like you have some of the values misconfigured.

The error `FirebaseError: Firebase: SAML Response <Issuer> mismatch.` should be referring to the Entity IDs not matching.

Start with making these 2 changes. You'll have to determine your SP Entity ID, it's likely your app's URL

[image]

Comment: can you please explain the two red arrows mentioned in the screenshot?
followed the response but still received the issuer mismatch error.
please find the screenshot here.

https://ibb.co/X3j8MXg

Comment: @scottwtang, Did we find solution for the problem? We are too facing this same issue

Comment: @DevVyaas I've updated the image in my answer which should be more clear

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya I've updated the image in my answer which should be more clear