SAML Authentication Error - Why is the user authenticated per Azure AD User Logs but Firebase SAML not returning user credentials?
I am using Firebase SAML for my application with base authentication services from Azure AD which contains my organisations users details. I am also using AWS Cognito for providing the SAML as this app will be served through AWS in the end. Below is my code for Index.js where I have imported all firebase resource and configured the code for signing in with SAML:
// SAML Authentication Attempt

//Setting session persistence
setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Session persistence set to browserSessionPersistence");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    console.error("Error setting persistence", error);
    // Fallback to inMemoryPersistence if browserSessionPersistence fails
    setPersistence(auth, inMemoryPersistence)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Fallback to inMemoryPersistence");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error setting inMemory Persistence", error)
      })
  })


// SAML
function ssoSignIn() {
  const provider = new SAMLAuthProvider('saml.saml-aws-iam');
  signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error during signInWithRedirect:", error)
    })
 };

document.getElementById("ssoButton").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); //Prevent Form Submission
  ssoSignIn();
});


// Loading DOM before attaching event listener
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const ssoButton = document.getElementById("ssoButton");
  if (ssoButton) {
    ssoButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      ssoSignIn();
    })
  } else {
    console.error("ssoButton not found in the DOM");
  }

  // Check for redirect result after redirecting back from the SAML Provider
  getRedirectResult(auth)
    .then((result) => {
      if (result && result.user) {
        console.log("User signed in with SSO:", result.user);
        // Redirect
        window.location.href = "dashboard.html";
      } else {
        console.log("No user found after redirect. Result:", result);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error during getRedirectResult:", error);
    })

})

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    console.log("User is signed in:", user);
    window.location.href = "dashboard.html";
  } else {
    console.log("No user is signed in.")
  }
})

Based on the code, I expect the user to be redirect to 'Dashboard.html' or even for one of the console.log to return user's details. Instead, I am receiving the following error:
[Error] Error during getRedirectResult: – FirebaseError: Firebase: All <AudienceRestriction>s should contain the SAML RP entity ID: ' urn:amazon:cognito:sp:[MY-USER-POOL-ID]'. (auth/invalid-credential).
FirebaseError: Firebase: All <AudienceRestriction>s should contain the SAML RP entity ID: ' urn:amazon:cognito:sp:eu-west-2_cD0DvWqD2'. (auth/invalid-credential).
    (anonymous function) (index.js:126)

I cannot seem to find the answer to this in any existing forum or through documents, given all redirects are working and that the user log is showing that a user has been logged is confusing as to why this is not working.

Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71798948/firebase-auth-with-azure-saml-sso

@Sridevi nope, I have already implemented the changes from that forum several time :(
